# How to unpack python dictionary to variable based on keyword

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to unpack a dictionary based on keyword. if there is any better way than using get?

```
from typing import List
def unpack_dict( argus: List):
    for arg in argus:
        name = arg.get('name')
        state = arg.get('name')
        number = arg.get('name')
        #name, addr, number = arg?
unpack_dict([dict(name='apple', state='NY', number='123'), dict(name='google', state='MA', number='456')])
```

Comment: pass name, state, number into different function

Answer (score 0):

If you know each dict will have the same keys then you can just use multiple assignment and `operator.itemgetter`

```
getter = itemgetter('name', 'state', 'number')
def unpack_dict( argus: List):
    for arg in argus:
       name, state, number = getter(arg)
```

You can even assign them all in the for statement using `map`:

```
def unpack_dict( argus: List):
    for name, state, number in map(getter, argus):
```

Comment: i do not know the sequence of keyword's value from argus

Comment: Then your question is lacking in details. As in what are you doing with the values?

Comment: Edited to add in `operator.itemgetter` if that helps